# Bootstrap modal close button does not cause postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a boostrap modal, and here is the button to close it:

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
 <asp:Button ID="btnClose" CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="Close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" />
 </div>
```

The Button and modal form are nested in an update panel. But it does not trigger a postback so the update panel does not do its thing. If I remove data dismiss then it will not close the modal.

What could I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data-dismiss is javascript based and just hides the modal.  If you want the close button to postback, you'll need to use the OnClick property and add a method to handle that in your code-behind:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnClose" CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="Close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" OnClick="YourMethodNameGoesHere"/>
```

Then in your code-behind...do something:

```
protected void YourMethodNameGoesHere()
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the ASP Button like in your example

```
<div class="modal-footer">
     <asp:Button ID="btnClose" CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="Close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" />
</div>
```

just try the *UseSubmitBehavior="false"*

```
<div class="modal-footer">
   <asp:Button ID="btnClose" CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="Close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
</div>
```

this will close the modal and trigger a postback

Comment: this should be the accepted answer because the first one don't trigger a postback.